# I am currently fetching the Google Reviews for my business and dispalying on my website using the Google Places API. Can I sort by most recent?

Tags: google-places-api, google-reviews

The default five reviews you get in the response are filtered down to the most relevant, is there a way to instead filter down to the five most recent reviews?

I expected there to be a sort or filter option to display the five most recent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even open the docs? It says reviews_sort right there...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#reviews_sort

Comment: appreciate your kind response